# How can I use middleware so a user has to fill in a password before viewing a page/file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

For a website I'm building I need to password protect PDF files, for this I want to use middleware so everyone that wants to go to the route of the file will be redirected to a page where they'll have to fill in a password. When they fill in the correct password they will then be redirected to the file, if not they'll be redirected to their previous page.

I've been looking online for a way to do this, even been trying to find a way to encrypt the PDF files themselves, but couldn't find anything remotely close to what I am trying to achieve.

I hope somebody can help me with this issue, thank you in advance!

EDIT: In the picture below you can see how it's meant to be.

[image: ![Functional Design]

Comment: Are you looking for a way to generate password-protected PDF files, or for a way to add some passwort protection to routes? The second one looks like something you simply have to code on your own

Comment: I was thinking of a way to redirect the user to a page where he has to fill in a password when he tries to navigate to the page/file and if the password he filled in is correct, he'll be redirected to the file he's trying to reach. https://imgur.com/a/qu5tnmg This image will explain it better.

Comment: is the user authenticated? and does he write his own account's password?

Comment: The user logs in through oauth with AD, he does not have to fill in his password when logging in

Answer (score 1):

Before generating the link for the pdf .. you need to make a pop for asking username or email and password .. if that conditions is met ... then redirect the page to the pdf.

Comment: Can you explain further why either a username or the email address is needed?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need a controller to authenticate users credentials:

Your controller will look something like:

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    return view('PdfPage', ['authenticated' => true]);
} else {
    return view('PdfPage', ['authenticated' => false]);
}
```

And in your view page you can check the returned value you used like:

```
@if($authenticated)
    <div>Show this div only if the user is authenticated</div>
@else
    <div>User is not authenticated</div>
@endif
```

The above approach redirects to the same view, if you want to redirect to a different view (for example the previous page or an error page) simple in your controller in your else statement use the view page you want to redirect the user when he/she is not authenticated.

Something like:

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    return view('PdfPage', ['authenticated' => true]);
} else {
    return view('ErrorPage', ['authenticated' => false]);
}
```